# Stacked barplot is opposite order to legend?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, legend

A minor question about plotting stacked barplot in R.
The **stacked bars represent the series bottom-to-top**.
But the **legend always shows the series top-to-bottom**. I think that is also true with *`ggplot2::geom_bar`*

Is there any nicer idiom than using *`rev(...)`* twice inside either *`legend()`* or *`barplot()`* as in:

```
exports <- data.frame(100*rbind('Americas'=runif(6),'Asia'=runif(6),'Other'=runif(6)))
colnames(exports) <- 2004:2009
series_we_want <- c(1,2,3)
barplot( as.matrix(exports[series_we_want,]), col=mycolors, ...)
legend(x="topleft", legend=rev(rownames(exports)[series_we_want]), col=rev(mycolors) ...)
```

(If you omit one of the *`rev()'s`* the output is obviously meaningless. Seems like an enhance case for adding a single flag *`yflip=TRUE`* or *`yreverse=TRUE`*)

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible so maybe this in ggplot2:

    `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))`

Comment: @Tyler: Reproducible part added. I'm mainly asking about the basic *`graphics::barplot`*, where there is apparently no such option. To make people aware and to see if there is any better idiom.

Comment: trellis has the same problem. When I asked Deepayan for a workaround, he added as.table=TRUE, and noted that it is a result of Descartes obsession that the sky is good is above is positive.

Comment: Closing. Maybe Descartes should have stood on his head more ;-) @Dieter-Menne

Comment: You know, I have worked in bat echolocation before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got using your code:

```
exports <- data.frame(100*rbind('Americas'=runif(6),'Asia'=runif(6),'Other'=runif(6)))
colnames(exports) <- 2004:2009
series_we_want <- c(1,2,3)
barplot( as.matrix(exports[series_we_want,]))
legend(x="topleft", legend=rev(rownames(exports)[series_we_want]))
```

[image]

try this:

```
exports <- data.frame(100*rbind('Americas'=runif(6),'Asia'=runif(6),'Other'=runif(6)))
colnames(exports) <- 2004:2009
series_we_want <- c(1,2,3)
test_data<-as.matrix(exports[series_we_want])

 barplot( test_data, 
          legend.text=as.character(rev(rownames(exports)[series_we_want])), 
           args.legend = list(x="topleft"))
```

seems to produce the legend in the opposite order of what you have

[image]

Comment: I think the OP can do that but they wanted to avoid the double `rev` use.  IMHO the double rev isn't a big deal and likely this is as easy as it gets since `legend` does not appear to have an argument to do this.

Comment: Well, I don't like it, but it works... ;-) I think another instance where `graphics::barplot` does almost what you want, but not quite, and isn't customizable, so `ggplot` better.